# Django + mod_wsgi => "No module named models" error

Tags: django, apache, django-models, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I need some help with unresolvable Django errors.

My website works very well when I "python manage.py runserver", but when I try to deploy it using wsgi, it keeps making unknown errors. I tried my best to google these errors, but I can't resolve it. Could anyone tell what my error is?

Apache error log

```
[error] /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/middleware/csrf.py:262: DeprecationWarning: CsrfResponseMiddleware and CsrfMiddleware are deprecated; use CsrfViewMiddleware and the template tag instead (see CSRF documentation).
[error]   DeprecationWarning
[error] [client 76.191.24.242] mod_wsgi (pid=21082): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/srv/www/myapp/wsgi.py'.
[error] [client 76.191.24.242] Traceback (most recent call last):
[error] [client 76.191.24.242]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 250, in __call__
[error] [client 76.191.24.242]     self.load_middleware()
[error] [client 76.191.24.242]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 47, in load_middleware
[error] [client 76.191.24.242]     raise exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured('Error importing middleware %s: "%s"' % (mw_module, e))
[error] [client 76.191.24.242] ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing middleware backends: "No module named models"
```

wsgi.py

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.append('/srv/www')
sys.path.append('/srv/www/myapp')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myapp.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

Apache

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName www.myapp.com
    DocumentRoot /srv/www/myapp

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.myapp.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.myapp.com$1 [R,L]

    Alias /static/ /srv/www/myapp/static/

    <Directory /srv/www/myapp>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory /srv/www/myapp/static>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess myapp.djangoserver processes=2 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP}
    WSGIProcessGroup myapp.djangoserver
    WSGIScriptAlias / /srv/www/myapp/wsgi.py

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Please show your `settings` and project tree structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message looks that you use Django 1.3 series and that you customized MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES by `backends.SomeClass` (some class defined in some module named `backends`) that was on development server in the current directory or at python path, but not so if started by mod_wsgi.

Full names of middleware classes should be used and verified that necessary python paths are added on the production server. Use eventually sys.path.append in wsgi.py file. It looks that on development server you added directory of some package to python path and you wrote short name ('backends') whereas you should add the parent directory of this package to sys.path and write full name.

(For sure - if you use it: If you use virtualenv, verify that sys.executable is the python executable from that virtualenv directory, not from normal Python. Forgotten virtualenv should be not be tried fixed by adding paths.)